# Are ARCore features on a desktop PC possible?

Tags: augmented-reality, desktop, arcore, simulate

Is it possible to run/simulate ARCore on a desktop PC? The idea is that users with low end phones can still use ARCore's features. I want the users to upload their videos with all required data for ARCore (clicks, accelerometer, gyroscope etc.) to a desktop pc server, linux or windows does not matter, and I want the desktop pc to apply ARCore features.

For example simulating the video stream and placing objects on the clicked location on the PC instead of on a smartphone. The PC could then for example send a video back with the results.

Kind regards,

Yorick

Answer (score 1):

ARCore features are accessible on a desktop PC but only inside **virtual emulator** (AVD) in Android Studio. To find out how to install and run AVD along with ARCore SDK on your PC read [Can't Install ARCore on emulator for Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49818161/cant-install-arcore-on-emulator-for-android-studio/55567156#55567156) SO post.

[image]

Hope this helps.