# Cannot Install ARCore on Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, augmented-reality, arcore, android-developer-api

I understand this question has been asked a few times, however the solutions for the other users have not resolved my issue.  I am attempting to install ARCore on my Android Studio emulator.  The Play Store says "Your device isn't compatible with this version," and when I click and drag the ARCore for emulator APK to manually install it on the emulator, it gives me the following message: "The APK failed to install. Error: Could not parse error string"

The System Image I'm using: Oreo/ API Version 27/ABI x86/Android 8.1 (Google Play)

I have set the OpenGL ES API level to Render Maximum, and its version is showing up as OpenGL ES 3.1.

I have tried every solution I could find on here and have had no luck.  Has anyone else had this issue or can you offer any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

> ***If your smartphone doesn't support ARCore or you have no phone but need to debug an AR app – Android emulator is a great way to do it***.

**Follow these steps to install Android Virtual Device (AVD)**:

- Make sure Android Debug Bridge (`adb`) is installed and works properly.
- Download the latest [ARCore_emulator.apk](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/releases) from ***GitHub***.
- Choose AVD using menu **`Tools`** > **`AVD Manager`** and run it.
- Type this command in Terminal ***while the virtual device is running***:

  ```
  adb install -r ARCore_1.8.0.x86_for_emulator.apk
  ```
- Repeat previous steps for additional AVDs you’d like to use on port 5554.

**If you need more detailed information, please read [THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49818161/cant-install-arcore-on-emulator-for-android-studio/55567156#55567156)**.

Comment: This worked! I had to run the command twice since the first time it showed "failed to install", but the second time worked.

Comment: @QauseenMZ I think this post will be useful for you as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49818161/cant-install-arcore-on-emulator-for-android-studio/55567156#55567156

Answer (score 0):

Followed Andy's Answer as follows:

- Make sure adb is installed by typing `adb` at any terminal. *

1) Downloaded Google_Play_Services_for_AR_1.14_x86_for_emulator.apk from [Android SDK Google Services](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/releases) (download it from latest release)

2) Copied this ***_x86_for_emulator.apk to the project root folder

3) Create new or Edit/Update existing Emulator with the instructions on the docs: [How to create an Emulator with ARCore Support](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/emulator)
i.e you must have emulators settings done.

4) Run the emulator

5) Open the terminal at Project Root (or anywhere you copied the ***_x86_for_emulator.apk file) and execute:

`adb install -r Google_Play_Services_for_AR_1.14_x86_for_emulator.apk` or

`adb install -r <name_x86_for_emulator>.apk`

5) Now run the project on same emulator. You can update rest of the emulators with these steps, providing that they have settings as given in Step 3.