# Is there a way to develop ARCore without a supported device?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore

Sorry for asking a stupid question. I would like to know that is there any way to develop ARCore app without a supported device?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, you can debug ARCore apps without any smartphone. For this you need to use an **Android Virtual Device** (AVD) in Android Studio.

> Go to this link to find out how to [install ARCore on Android Virtual Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53663547/cannot-install-arcore-on-android-emulator/55831766#55831766).
>
> Or look at this answer: [Can't Install ARCore on emulator for Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49818161/cant-install-arcore-on-emulator-for-android-studio/55567156#55567156).

[image]

Comment: What for? AVD is inside Android Studio IDE. There's no need for such a compatibility. Android Studio is self-sufficient.