# RealityKit Collaborative Session Debugging

Tags: swift, xcode, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I want to make AR Apps with RealityKit Collaborative Session.
It seems needed to use multiple device, not simulator for me.
I have an actual device only one.

Can I debug with simulator and an actual device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Xcode 15, there is still no `RealityKit iOS Simulator` for AR projects (like [ARCore Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49818161/cant-install-arcore-emulator-for-android-studio/55567156#55567156) that you can find in Android Studio). However, now `visionOS Simulator` is accessible for you.

When you're building iOS RealityKit apps with a Collaborative Session feature in Xcode, **you need at least 2 real Apple devices** – AR Collaborative Session supports up to 6 devices.

Comment: Thanks! I understood.